# Python WebScraping Confusion

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I tried to webscrape a HTML webpage, https://streamelements.com/logna/leaderboard, but the HTML code that I can see in inspect element with Firefox is different to the HTML source code of the webpage.

Is it possile to webscrape webpages like this or is there a way to get the code you can see through inspect element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Html code seen from inspect tool may differ from the original source code. It is because all the js and php code are rendered by the browser. So, while doing web scraping  you should consider the HTML code as seen on browser npt the original source code.

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: How do you webscrape html code thats displayed on the browser and now html code thats found in the source code?

Comment: @ParsleyPurr It seems you have never tried Selenium in python.

Comment: No I haven't but I'll check it out and learn about it. Thanks for the tip!